# JavaScript code not working

Tags: javascript

I want to make text editable by converting it to textfield . i just wanted to try it in my browser so i copied it and paste it in Dreamweaver but its not working:

you can find it here : http://jsfiddle.net/cnuDh/

but its not working

the code is below

```
<label id="edit" style="cursor:pointer; color:blue;">
  edit
</label>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td>Wright</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('#edit').click(function () {
    var $table = $('table');
    if ($table.find('input').length) return;
    $table.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(function (i, v) {
        return '<input value=' + v + '>';
    })
})
$('table').on('blur', 'input', function () {
    $('table input').replaceWith(function () {
        return this.value;
    })
})
</script>
```

Any help please

Comment: even i have trouble with syntax .. if you have firefox you can use a tool called 'firebug' that will show you javascript errors when they occur in the error console.

Comment: Have you added the jquery to your page ?

Comment: please mention what error u face it

Comment: no i didnt add any jquery. no errors shown

Comment: you need to add jquery if you want to use it. look at the answers below they got examples on how to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the jQuery Library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add jQuery to the page to able to use its selectors as well as  `$(document).ready()` to load the scripts as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#edit').click(function() {
          var $table = $('table');
          if ($table.find('input').length) return;
          $table.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(function(i, v) {
            return '<input value=' + v + '>';
          })
        })
        $('table').on('blur', 'input', function() {
          $('table input').replaceWith(function() {
            return this.value;
          })
        })
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label id="edit" style="cursor:pointer; color:blue;">edit</label>
    <table>
      <tr><td>First Name: </td>
          <td>John</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Last Name: </td>
          <td>Wright</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem! Need to get your fundamentals right. Don't forget to mark my answer too if it makes you a happy person!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

edit

```
<table>
<tr><td>First Name: </td>
    <td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Last Name: </td>
    <td>Wright</td>
</tr>
```

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
   var $table = $('table');
   if ($table.find('input').length) return;
   $table.find('td:nth-child(2)').html(function(i, v) {
     return '<input value=' + v + '>';
  })

  })


$('table').on('blur', 'input', function() {
$('table input').replaceWith(function() {
    return this.value;
})
})
```

Comment: The code is ok, to me it worked.

Comment: Should be careful with those double forward slashes.

Comment: it still not working:(

Comment: add directly <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>.

Comment: first of all you need to download the jQuery library or upload directly to the site.Read here: http://jquery.com/download/